# NGINX Fallback to alternative upstream on 502 and 503

Tags: nginx

We have two NGINX gateways A and B on different hosts listening on port 8080 and each with their own set of microservices (port 8081-8089) on localhost.

We want each gateway to prefer it's own local services and fallback to the other gateway in case of failure.

```
location /app1/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  error_page 502 = @gateway2;
  error_page 503 = @gateway2;
}
location @gateway2 {
  proxy_pass http://gateway2:8080$request_uri;
}
```

If a local microservice on Gateway A is not available the gateway will handle this as a 502 and we have configured NGINX using `error_page` to send the request to the microservice on Gateway B. This works fine in the case of no response (502 bad gateway).

However, if the local microservice is not "ready" (let's say DB not connected) it returns a 503.

Unfortunately NGINX is not catching this 503 as it does with 502 - it does not fallback to @gateway2 but sends the 503 back to the client. Why?

Comment: Try adding `proxy_intercept_errors on;`

Comment: That solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `proxy_intercept_errors on;`

```
Syntax: proxy_intercept_errors on | off;
Default:    
proxy_intercept_errors off;
Context:    http, server, location
```

> Determines whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be intercepted and redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive.